# A necessary and sufficient condition for k-connectivity

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

Here's another problem I've been trying for some time with no good results whatsoever:

"Let $G$ be a connected graph which is not complete. Then $G$ is k-connected if and only if every pair of vertices with distance two are connected by k internally disjoint paths."

Basically it tells it is sufficient to check k-connectivity on vertices with distance two.

The only thing I'm sure is that you can't apply induction hypotheses on k because if k+1 is even then k is odd and to have such k-regular subgraph  the number of vertices of $G$ has to be even also. The number of vertices of odd order is even.

Maybe grabbing two vertices, making cases and taking advantage of their neighbors works but I can't seem to give a general argument.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement without the restriction that the distance has to be two is called (vertex version of) *[Menger's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem)*. The induction proof is a bit tricky.

You can look at the one [linked](http://www.math.unm.edu/~loring/links/graph_s05/Menger.pdf) in the Wikipedia article.

Now it remains to show that if the graph is not $k$ connected, then there are two vertices of distance two that have less than $k$ internally disjoint paths:

As $G$ is not $k$ connected there is some set $X \subset V(G)$ with $|X| \leq k-1$ such that $G-X$ is disconnected and $X$ is minimal with that property (subsets of it don't disconnect $G$).

Menger gives us (note that $G$ is $|X|$ connected) that there must be some vertices $x,y \in V(G)$ and a $x-y$ path $P$ that contains exactly one element of $z \in X$ such that in $G-X$ those vertices are disconnected.

Now look at the vertices $r,s$ directly before and directly after $z$ on $P$. Clearly we have $\text{dist}_G(r,s)\leq \text{dist}_P(r,s)=2 $. But as $r,s$ can't be connected in $G$ (otherwise removing $|X|$ would not disconnect $x$ and $y$) we also have $\text{dist}_G(r,s)\geq 2$ and thus $\text{dist}_G(r,s)=2$.

Note that $r,s \notin X$, as $V(P)\cap X=\{z\}$ and that $r,s$ can be separated by $X$, thus by Menger there are less than $k$ internally disjoint $r-s$ paths.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I think Menger's theorem would be the statement without the words "distance two".

Comment: @serge Thanks, I missed that. I tried to fix the proof for what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a lot of trouble building good intuition in a lot of problems in graph theory.